# symbolic link not created

Tags: macos, symlink

All my docs are in:

```
/Users/Joe/Documents/Mydocs
```

I want to put them on dropbox through symbolic link so I created this empty folder:

```
/Users/Joe/Dropbox/Mydocs
```

Then used this command to create a symbolic link:

```
ls -s /Users/Joe/Documents/Mydocs /Users/Joe/Dropbox/Mydocs
```

The destination folder is still empty, what can I do to properly make the link?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your command is wrong.

It is not `ls -s`, but `ln -s`

Answer (score 4):

As [Vincent](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/30203/vincent) points out, the proper command is `ln -s`, not `ls -s`. In addition to that, `ln` will throw an error if the target of the link (in this case, the `Mydocs` folder in Dropbox) already exists.

The proper way to do this is to delete `/Users/Joe/Dropbox/Mydocs`, then run `ln -s /Users/Joe/Documents/Mydocs /Users/Joe/Dropbox/Mydocs`.